# Sum of Most Significant digits of two large numbers of char type

Tags: c, arrays, optimization, char

I have two numbers of char type say

```
char* N1;
char* N2;

N1 = "92345610172222";
N2 = "12351097654671";
```

I need to add MSD's of two numbers i.e

9 + 1 = 10

I solved by typecasting and dividing the number until it encounters a single digit using two loops.Sum it and return the result.

```
int sumMsd(char *N1, char *N2) {
    int one = (int)*N1;
    int two = (int)*N2;
    while (one >= 10)
        one /= 10;
    while (two >= 10)
        two /= 10;
    return one+two;
}
```

The logic fails when int size is very large. So,I need to optimize my solution without using library functions. I am looking out for a solution in C.

Comment: `return (*N1 - '0') + (*N2 - '0');`

Comment: Wouldn't the most significat digit just be the first character?

Comment: Since you want to add the most significant digits, do you want to skip leading zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
int sumMsd(char *N1, char *N2) {
    return (N1[0] - '0') + (N2[0] - '0');
}
```

Let the first digit of N1 be '3'. Then '3' - '0' is 3, the difference between their ASCII values.

Comment: Assumes ASCII character encodings -- don't try this on an EBCDIC host. There, you'd have to use atoi(3), violating OP's "without using library functions" caveat. Yes, most hosts currently encountered would use ASCII encodings for digits.

Comment: @mpez0 Disagree with [don't try this on an EBCDIC host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54328882/sum-of-most-significant-digits-of-two-large-numbers-of-char-type#comment95479209_54329074).  What about `(N1[0] - '0') + (N2[0] - '0')` would not work with EBCDIC as all C encoding is done with contiguous '0', '1','2', ... '9'?  be it EBCDIC, ASCII, etc.

Comment: @mpez0 the C standard mandates that digit characters are encoded sequentially, therefore `*N - '0'` will always work. See 5.2.1 3 which states *... the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.*

Comment: Yes, I spoke too soon. Digits in EBCIDIC are contiguous; the alphabet is not